# Latest Research Topics in Software Quality Assurance

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, test-management, quality-assessment, quality-assurance

Research Scope in **Software Quality Assurance**.

I do not know from where I have to find latest challenges in SQA or scope where is now SQA and where was it is? Is there any suggestion that how can I find good topics in SQA field which is hot now a days. From where I have to start to find the latest or future work about SQA. I hear about [IEEE Xplore Digital Library](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/home.jsp) but it is not free.

Thanks for your positive response.

Comment: Atif Memon at the University of Maryland does a lot of research in software testing.  His website is [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~atif/).  You will not find a complete list of all "hot" topics in SQA, but if you read some of his papers and follow the references, you may find something that interests you.

Comment: Start with finding a good advisor. http://academia.stackexchange.com/ would be good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Testing usually falls to a tester/ test engineer, the designing and maintenance of test cases, writing necessary testing code and all the meta-work usually falls to a team lead such as an SQA engineer.

To help build a software quality assurance and testing toolbox, here is a list of tips, tools, tutorials, blogs, services, and miscellaneous other resources -

**Blogs**

http://googletesting.blogspot.com/

http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/

http://gojko.net/

http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/

http://www.ministryoftesting.com/news/

http://qablog.practitest.com/

**FAQs & Tips**

http://www.softwareqatest.com/

http://www.stickyminds.com/

http://www.agiledata.org/

http://www.qatutor.com/

http://apps.testinsane.com/mindmaps/

This site as well : https://sqa.stackexchange.com/

**Web and Mobile Testing Tips & Techniques**

http://www.mobileqazone.com/

http://testdroid.com/

http://www.belatrixsf.com/index.php/whitepaper-mobile-testing-best-practices-m

http://x-mirage.com/x-mirage/

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-bestdevops-mobileapps/

For **more** details please refer this link : http://www.computersciencezone.org/software-quality-assurance/

Also refer this link : http://soft.vub.ac.be/~cderoove/software_quality/